# how to get English tweets alone using python?

Tags: python, twitter, nltk

Here is my current code

```
from twitter import *

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET, 
        ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET))

t.statuses.home_timeline()
query=raw_input("enter the query \n")
data = t.search.tweets(q=query)

for i in range (0,1000):    
    print data['statuses'][i]['text']
    print '\n'
```

Here, I fetch tweets from all the languages. Is there a way to restrict myself to fetching tweets only in English?

Comment: oh God! Why the semicolons?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031393/how-to-restrict-the-language-of-results-in-twitter4j-to-english) might point in the right direction; Worst case scenario, peek into the source of the Twitter module to see if they expose the `lang` parameter.

Comment: Isn't that `OAuth` bit unsafe to post on stackoverflow? I'm not positive, but it looks like it might allow anyone reading this to authenticate as the poster of this question..

Comment: johannestaas , thank you for your information ,  i really forgot about it

Comment: Please disable your keys and get new ones. We can remove the edit, but it’s already much too late if you want to feel safe about anything.

Comment: No easy solution that I am aware of. You can stem tweets, or check for most common words such as `the, this, that, me` etc. But how will you deal with something like `idk who r u`?

Comment: Your best bet is to run some kinda of NLP  algorithm http://nltk.org/

Comment: stemming and all other preprocessing are done , I also tried using the ascii code ,but for languages that contain English alphabets this cannot be done ,other languages can be filtered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least 4 ways... I put them in the order of simplicity.

1. After you collect the tweets, the json output has a key/value pair that identifies the language. So you can use something like this to take all language tweets and select only the ones that are from English accounts.

   ```
   for i in range (0,1000):
      if data['statuses'][i][u'lang']==u'en':
         print data['statuses'][i]['text']
         print '\n'
   ```
2. Another way to collect only tweets that are identified in English, you can use the optional 'lang' parameter to request from the API only English (self-idenfitied) tweets. See details [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). If you are using the [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) library, you can set the 'lang' parameter in [twitter.py](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter.py).
3. Use a language recognition package like [guess-language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494526/2327328).
4. Or if you want to recognize English text without using the self-identified twitter data (i.e. a chinese account that is writing in English), then you have to do Natural Language Processing. [One option](http://nltk.org/). This method will recognize common English words and then mark the text as English.

Answer (score 0):

I try this for farsi:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth) 

res = api.search('lang','fa')
for i in res:
    print( i.lang)
```